# Getting FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to build an iOS application via React Native, the app builds successfully but I am launching it, I am getting this error:

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-13 05:26:36 +0000";
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x29b0;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "launchApplicationWithID:options:pid:error:";
}
--
The request to open "com.abc.xyz" failed.
Domain: FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = RequestDenied;
    FBSOpenApplicationRequestID = 0x29b0;
}
--
The operation couldn't be completed. The process failed to launch.
Domain: FBProcessExit
Code: 64
Failure Reason: The process failed to launch.
User Info: {
    BSErrorCodeDescription = "launch-failed";
}
--
The operation couldn't be completed. Launch failed.
Domain: RBSRequestErrorDomain
Code: 5
Failure Reason: Launch failed.
--
Launchd job spawn failed
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 111
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone16,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.0 (21A328)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 131285;
    "operation_errorCode" = 1;
    "operation_errorDomain" = FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A344)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-10-13T10:56:36+05:30
```

Ruby version - `3.0.3`
IOS - `17`
pods version - `1.12.1`

I have tried resetting the simulator, deleting the derived data, restarting the device, and deleting the cache. Nothing works.